# How to change the spacing of formula objects in Libreoffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

I'm inserting scientific formulae into a document in Libreoffice Writer within a paragraph using **Insert>Object>Formula**, and the spacing either side of the formula object is too large for the required formatting.

For example after the object any punctuation, like a full stop, is displaced too far from the formula. Can I change the general settings of formula objects so that they all have a user specified spacing?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to your own answer, in order to affect **all** formulas in a document, you need to change formula frame style. This can be done this way (refer to the image below):

1. Navigate to `Styles` menu (or `F11` and proceed to step 3)
2. Select `Manage Styles` from there
3. In the appeared right panel select `Frame Styles` from the top row
4. Right-click `Formula` entry from there
5. From the drop-down menu select `Modify...`
6. In the appeared window navigate to `Wrap` tab
7. Modify spacing as you wish in the corresponding section
8. Don't forget to apply

[image: Steps to change style of formulas]

Answer (score 2):

I found the wrapping options and have solved the issue for specific formula objects.

For those experiencing the same issue:

1. Right click on the object (in my case a formula).
2. From the options that appear in the drop down menu select "Object" (you can also press the "o" key as a shortcut). This will bring up a new widow showing that object's specific properties.
3. From the available tabs in this window click on "Wrap".
4. You should see a window like the one shown below; under the "Spacing" heading check to see what the spacing distance is for "Left" and "Right".

[image]

5. Set the values in "Left" and "Right" to zero (or any other setting you may need). Then click "OK".

Note: This will only effect the settings for that particular object, not all objects in you file.